# Restart Tomcat from Jenkins (no tty present)

Tags: tomcat, jenkins

I would like to restart Tomcat from Jenkins. I added a step to execute:

`sudo service tomcat restart`

but I get:

`no tty present and no askpass program specified`

If i try

`service tomcat restart`

I get:

```
Stopping Tomcatsu: must be run from a terminal
```

I added in /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty
%jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD:/etc/init.d/tomcat restart
%jenkins ALL=(jenkins : jenkins) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

But the result is the same. I wuold really appreciate any help with this issue. Are there anyway to solve it? Or are there any other way to restart Tomcat from Jenkins?

Thanks in advance.